# Store DbGeography polygons on sql Server 2008 r2 as text

Tags: c#, sql-server, geography

At the moment I have polygons stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 geography column. So that I can work with them in c# I use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types v11.0.2 nuget package. I have had problems publishing to Windows 7 where it wont install the correct versions of the CLR types. I would like to stop using the CLR types because of the hassles with publishing. Can I use the DbGeography type with c# and store the polygons on SQL  Server with a nVarChar type or some other text type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for **[STAsText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933977.aspx)**

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 3)', 0);
SELECT @g.STAsText();
```